# Map tip display text in QGIS 2.16: pictures not showing up anymore!

Tags: qgis, maptips

I've been using the great function of QGIS: **"map tips"**. It allows to include html-formatted text (and pictures) in order to popup a window by hovering features.
I use map tips for a very convenient visualization of georeferenced pictures, as I presented once on [digital-geography blog](http://www.digital-geography.com/combinig-qgis-and-leaflet-to-visualize-an-area-with-pictures/#.V9-xgLP9q00)

But sadly I cannot make it woking anymore since (?) few weeks, I think since I updated QGIS to 2.16.1 (and later 2.16.2)!
I'm always using the same code as before:

`[%CONCAT('<img src="/path/to/my/georef/pictures/',"filename",'" width="400"></img>')%]`

*(I know it can be written in an other way but this was working before...)*

Now the frame popping up but there's just no picture
[image]
Is that a consequence of the map tips improvements of QGIS 2.16? Is there a new syntax I'm missing?
Or I might have something going wrong on my comp?

Anyone sharing the issue? Any ... tip?

**Note** that including an Iframe link works, I tried the code proposed by mbernasocchi answering to the question "How to view a video using map-tip QGIS 2.16" and it works great.

I'm working under Kubuntu 14.04
kdelibs: 4.13.3
Qt: 4.8.6
Core: 4.2.0-42-generic
System: 32 bit

Comment: Did you leave a bug report?

Comment: Not yet, I wanted first to send this question and see if other people meet this issue or if it's rather a local problem on my comp. But you're right I'll do it!

Comment: After trying, I have the same issue (linux). Photos however still show in forms with same links.

Comment: You did not done it, I had to do (https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15658). And it not works great with iframe, the scollbars are still there annoyingly.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I think I'm seeing the same thing, but the photo shows up if I move my cursor off the point, then back on.

Comment: @Brian Fisher May: nope still no success, still empty frame. I should try on another comp to know if the problem is connected to my config or not ... but I didn't yet. I'll send a report when I do it.

Comment: I tried to use the form you indicate with Qgis3.2.3 `<img src="file://[% @project_home %]/[% "your_relative_picture_path" %]" />` but the result is a question mark with both JPG and PNG files.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmB2L.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmB2L.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the `file://` prefix.
The most portable way to use this (assuming you have the images in the same folder as the project) currently (tested on QGIS 3.2 - ubuntu) is:

`<img src="file://[%  @project_home  %]/[% "your_relative_picture_path" %]" />`

you can also add `width="300" and height="300"` or so if needed

please note the `@project_home` this is a QGIS variable that is automatically set on each project thus allowing you to maintain relative paths

Comment: The answer solved my question. I came to it after a looooooong time! The structure <img src="file:///any-method-to-insert-the-path" /> worked. I used src='...' instead src="..." to disambiguate use of ' and ". I also added style="width: 100%;" to force the picture fitting in the frame. Note the if you don't use the variable @project_home but, like it was in my case, a fixed path, you should start the path with file:///

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
<div style="width:400;height:320">
<div style="height:20; margin: 0 auto;">
[% "filename" %]
</div>
<div style="height:300; margin: 0 auto;">
<img style="max-width:400px; max-height:300px;" src="[% "filepath" %]" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I had no time yet for that. I tried your answer without success, still getting a blank frame without picture!

Comment: SzieberthAdam, without path QGIS won't find my pictures for sure. I don't understand your comment. BTW I'm more and more believing that the problem is on my comp, not in QGIS :-/

Comment: I have explicite attributes for filepath and filename separately. The above code prints the filename only and displays the image below based on full filepath info. I was mistaken you do a string concatenation which is not necessary IMO. I meant you should replace `src="[% "filepath" %]"` with `src="/path/to/my/georef/pictures/[% "filename" %]"` in the above code. Good luck to find the root of your problem!