# Adding images in Text Annotations using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to add an image in a zone, on the map, to show that an event ocurred.
I don't mind if it is in an Annotation Text or any other functionality.

Is it possible somehow in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: There is the [HTML Annotation](https://plus.google.com/+NathanWoodrow/posts/ETF5p4f622G) where you can add the path of your image.

Comment: @Joseph it seems it is not working right now... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211117/map-tip-display-text-in-qgis-2-16-pictures-not-showing-up-anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It requires an extra step in separate software but if you wanted to use annotations what you could do is:

1. In [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) you could import your image and then save the image as an .svg file
2. In QGIS add an SVG annotation (selected from the dropdown next to the add text annotation) and select your svg.  The image will appear and you can resize is like any other annotation.

[image]